# How to fix "Windows fatal exception: code 0xc06d007e" when trying to plot a pandas column using matplotlib library?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

my train_df is a comparatively large dataframe mostly categorical columns. I am trying to plot bars for specific columns of this dataframe using visual studio code in windows 10. However, I am receiving the following error message and not getting the plot. Is the error the reason behind not showing the plot?

```
 ORGANISM Windows fatal exception: code 0xc06d007e
 
 Current thread 0x00002a24 (most recent call first):   File
 "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5 in dot   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py",
 line 2008 in rotate   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py",
 line 2020 in rotate_deg   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py",
 line 2042 in rotate_deg_around   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py",
 line 754 in get_patch_transform   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py",
 line 278 in get_transform   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
 line 790 in set_clip_path   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line
 935 in set_clip_path   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py",
 line 1300 in cla   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py",
 line 632 in __init__   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py",
 line 456 in wrapper   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py",
 line 34 in __init__   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
 line 772 in add_subplot   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py",
 line 305 in subplots   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
 line 897 in subplots   File
 "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
line 1435 in subplots   File "c:\Users\username\.../myhelper.py", 
line 418 in plotter_func1 File "c:/Users/username/.../myscript.py",
line 175 in main File "c:/Users/username/.../myscript.py", 
line 180 in <module>
```

Comment: Thank you Albert for the edit,

Comment: Since python is not giving me any helpful error message, I am sure that I have not created the issue but it is rather a python bug itself or a windows issue given that I found a memory warning while checking my "Event View".